# Git independent branches in different folders with already existing repo

Tags: eclipse, git, branch, git-branch, orphan

I created a git repo with some of my projects, the folder structure looks something like this:

```
workspace
- project1    
- project2  
- ...
- run
```

while run is a folder that all of them use.

I didn't know how to do it so I just named commits like this:

```
[Project1] updated this
[Project2] fixed that
[Project2] added this feature
...
```

So, is it possible to split the projects to independent branches?
the run folder should also be included in the work-space and used by all projects.

Answer (score 0):

**What you could do**

What you want is rather different repos than different branches.

In practice you could:

- Create a repository per project and one for `run`. (If you want to keep your files history surgically you may refer to [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository).)
- Create another Git project at the top and reference the other repos as [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules), in order to keep the same filesystem.

**Why I believe you don't want to use branches**

As far as I understand you'd like to try a workflow which would look like:

```
A - B - C - D - E (branch for project1)
          \
            F - G (branch for project2)
```

Where

- `C` is your current commit
- `D` and `E` are commits made when you worked only on `project1`
- `F` and `G` are commits made when you worked only on `project2`

In practice, if you want to work on `project1` you're going to checkout `E`. So your workspace will look like

```
workspace
- project1 in the state of commit E   
- project2 in the state of commit C
- ...
- run
```

What I mean is you'll keep each project in your workspace, all be frozen at commit `C` except the one you're working one. Which, I believe, isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: So it is not possible with those "orphan" branches?

Comment: Just editer my answer to explain why I believe it's not what you're looking for

Comment: So how would I move all commits into a submodule?
I have to create new repos for every project, right? And what then?